# Convert a string to datetime object in python

Tags: python

I have a date string defined as followed:

```
datestr = '2011-05-01'
```

I want to convert this into a datetime object so i used the following code

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d')
print dateobj
```

But what gets printed is: 2011-05-01 00:00:00. I just need 2011-05-01. What needs to be changed in my code ?

Thank You

Comment: This is a question that could easily have been answered by reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

Comment: @BjörnPollex I just found this question and it helped me within 10 seconds. Finding the answer on the documentation page would have taken me a lot longer than that. StackOverflow is popular for a reason, and it's not a bad reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dateobj.date()` will give you the `datetime.date` object, such as `datetime.date(2011, 5, 1)`

Use:

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

See also: Python documentation on [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Kinda lame that it's necessary to create a datetime object and then throw away the time...

Comment: @MuMind: In this simple case, you could also use `datetime.date(*map(int, datestr.split("-")))` to create a `date` object directly.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, `datetime` objects always contain a date and a time.  If you don't need the time, simply ignore it.  To print it in the same format as before, use

```
print dateobj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
print dateobj
```